# Calculating the Limit of a Function

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, derivatives

I am doing 18.01SC from MIT OCW and got stuck at this question (pset1, 1J-2).

Calculate $$\lim_{x\to \pi/2} {\cos x \over x - \pi/2}$$ by relating it to a value of $ (\cos x)' $.

Failing to solve this question after several attempts, I looked up their given solutions and found this:

$$ \lim_{x\to \pi/2} {\cos x \over x - \pi/2} = \lim_{x\to \pi/2} {\cos x - \cos(\pi / 2) \over x - \pi/2} = \left.{d \over dx} (\cos x) \right| _{x = \pi/2} = -1$$

I do not understand the transition from the second part of the above equation to the third. Though I know how to calculate the derivative of a function from its difference quotient, I am unable to comprehend how the second equation can be  the result to the derivative of $\cos x $ when $ x = \pi/2 $. Please explain to me how this works.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: The 2nd step to the third is the limit definition of the derivative, think about $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ where $x$ approaches $a$. The answer then becomes $f'(a)$. It has got nothing to do with LHospital's Rule here (referring to an earlier answer)

Comment: There's a theorem says that if $f$ is differentiable on some space $(x_{1},x_{2})$, there's a number $\xi\in(x_{1},x_{2})$ such that $$f'(\xi)=\frac{f(x_{2})-f(x_{1})}{x_{2}-x_{1}}.$$ Now simplify for $f(x)=\cos(x)$ , for $x_{2}=x$ and $x_{1}=\frac{\pi}{2}.$

Comment: Suppose that $x=\frac{\pi}{2}+h$

Comment: @JohnJoy that was what I was missing. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of the derivative is

$$f'(x_0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$$

Now, let $f(x)=\cos(x)$ and enforce the substitution $h=x-x_0$ with $x_0=\pi/2$.  Then, we have

$$\left.\frac{d\,\cos(x_0)}{dx_0}\right|_{x_0=\pi/2}=\lim_{x\to \pi/2}\frac{\cos(x)-\cos(\pi/2)}{x-\pi/2}$$

Comment: The substitution $ h = x - x_0 $ is what I was missing in my understanding. Thank you for your help.

I realise that though I know the first formula you stated, I was unable to do the necessary substitution to get to the second formula.

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  Pleased to hear that this helped!!  -Mark

Comment: I was upvoting the other answer as it contained alternative definitions of derivatives that I didn't know about. However, somehow that toggled the accepted answer which I didn't intend to. This answer was the most useful one for me.

Comment: Thank you for your note.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You wrote:

> I know how to calculate the derivative of a function from its difference quotient,

To calculate the derivative from the difference quotient is to do the following:
$$
\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = f'(a) = \left. \frac d {dx} f(x) \right|_{x=a}.
$$
This is the case in which $f(x)=\cos x$ and $a=\dfrac\pi2$.

The answer relies on prior knowledge that $\cos'=-\sin$. This is not an attempt to prove that, but rather that is being used here.  How to prove that $\cos'=-\sin$ is another question, whose answer would be longer than this.

Comment: In realm of what the OP is trying to do, this answer is the best in my view...

Comment: Thank you for your help. The difference quotient as I know is different from the one you wrote (mine is from the definition of the derivative). Now I understand that you can proceed from the second to the third step by either using substitution or the method you stated.

Comment: @MohideenImranKhan : This one is from the definition of "derivative" which states either $$ f'(a) = \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} $$ or $$ f'(a) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a+h) - f(a)} h $$ or $$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}.$$ I don't think these can be considered quite different from each other; they all say exactly the same thing. $\qquad$

Comment: I understand that now. When I was learning, I only had a partial understanding which is now more complete thanks to the help provided here.

Answer (score 2):

Hint $\cos(x)=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)$ so now can you use standard result related to sin to get answer as $-1$